# Is it true that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha e^{-\beta\log^\gamma x}=0$ for all positive $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$? Would L'Hôpital help?

Tags: limits

> Is it true that 
>   $$\displaystyle\lim_{ x \rightarrow \infty} x^\alpha e^{-\beta \log^\gamma x} =0$$
>   for all positive $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$?

I think so, but I can't prove it. Sorry if the question is trivial, but I tried an approach using the L'Hôpital's rule, but the denominator just complicated it and I couldn't conclude anything.
I think I'm trying a hard way. Any suggestions on a different idea I can use?

Comment: The rule is for undetermined forms only (I guess) - See: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LHospitalsRule.aspx

Comment: @NoChance There are obvious ways to attempt to use it here e.g. writing the limit as $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^\alpha}{e^{\beta \log^\gamma(x)}}$ which is a $\infty/\infty$ form in this situation.

Comment: Good point @Ian thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for L'Hopital, just a change of variable to make the limit easier to see.

If you let $x=e^u$ with $u\to\infty$, then, with $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\gt0$, we have

$$x^\alpha e^{-\beta\ln^\gamma x}=e^{\alpha u-bu^\gamma}\to
\begin{cases}
0\quad\text{if }\gamma\gt1\text{ or }\gamma=1\text{ and }\alpha\lt\beta\\
1\quad\text{if }\gamma=1\text{ and }\alpha=\beta\\
\infty\quad\text{if }\gamma\lt1\text{ or }\gamma=1\text{ and }\alpha\gt\beta\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ah, I see this is essentially the same answer as Ian's, just differently presented.

Comment: Thanks, Barry. Much better than the idea I had.

Answer (score 1):

The useful trick is to use the fact that if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \geq 0$ then it is equal to $\exp \left ( \lim_{x \to \infty} \log(f(x)) \right )$, with the understanding $e^{-\infty}=0$. So you have $\exp \left ( \lim_{x \to \infty} \alpha \log(x) - \beta \log(x)^\gamma \right )$. Now you can change variables in the limiting procedure to $u=\log(x)$, so that you have $\exp \left ( \lim_{u \to \infty} \alpha u - \beta u^\gamma \right )$. Can you do it from there?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ian.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. If $\alpha=\beta =\gamma=1$ the the function is identically $1$ so the limit is $1$.